Smallest codes with transversal cliffords
Is there a classification or database of codes which allow transversal implementation of the Clifford group? The only ref I know is this non-exhaustive list on the error correction zoo for any transversal gate https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/list/quantum_transversal.
More particularly, I'm interested in the smallest known codes which allow transversal Cliffords given other parameters like distance. Any bounds specific to Clifford codes might also be helpful.

This recent preprint High-distance codes with transversal Clifford and T-gates  contains  $[n, 1, d]$ code families that either admit a transversal implementation of the single-qubit Clifford group or a transversal implementation of the logical T-gate.
The code families require a lower qubit overhead than any other qubit stabilizer of the same distance which can realize these transversal gates.
This table contains an overview of the constructed codes. Codes that are doubly even allow for transversal implementation of the Clifford group. Codes that are triply even allow for transversal implementation of the logical T-gate.

I don't know of a reference containing the best known codes encoding more than 1 logical qubit with certain transversal gates. I do not think it is possible to have a code encoding multiple logical qubits for which the 2-qubit Clifford group can be performed transversally.
